# How to destroy an activity when switching to another activity via intent?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 3 activities A, B and C. Activity A has a button which when clicked takes me to Activity B. Activity B has a button which when clicked takes me to Activity C. When I click on button in Activity A it takes me to Activity B but Activity A is paused and not destroyed and the same happens when I click Activity B's button and go to acitivty C. I tried using finish() on activity B, but the problem is when I press the back button in activity C it goes directly to Activity A. What I want is when I click Activity B's button it should destroy Acitivity B and take me to Acitivity C and in Activity C, if I press back button it should take me to newly created activity B

Activity A -> Activity B-> Activity C

Comment: Whatever you are trying to achieve must be done in a simpler way. When you press button in ActivityB, why do you want to destroy it, since while coming from ActivityC, you want to land at ActivityB.

Comment: Yeah I know it can be achieved easily. The problem is I have a slidingUppanel in all activities (from baseactivity) and the ui of this panel is not updated when I press the back button on Activity C and come to Activity B.

Comment: But on recreation it works good. Idk the reason why.

Comment: Then why don't why update the ui of the panel in onStart() of ActivityB? Since onStart() will always be called either it is a new activity or a resumed activity.

Comment: Please have a look at this. I have tried to explain it as good as I can. https://stackoverflow.com/q/47239625/8745264

Answer (score 0):

You'll be working against the Android framework. That leads to frustrations. Instead, when you go to activity C, don't finish activity B. Instead, in activity B in onResume(), do something based on the fact that you went to activity C. Or starting Activity C using [startActivityForResult()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)) may be appropriate.

**Edited**

The problem is updating the UI after something changed in activity C. The best place to do that in activity B is in the onResume(). Put the logic for updating the UI in onResume() **instead of** in onCreate(). When an activity is created, onCreate() is invoked, and onResume() is also invoked.

Comment: Can you elaborate on startActivityForResult()?

Comment: Google for examples of it, but the idea of startActivityForResult() is that you start activity C to get some value or values from the user, and return that to activity B. I just threw that in there, because you haven't said why you want activity B to be recreated when returning from activity C (as opposed to resuming).

Comment: Okay. I want to recreate activity B because I have a sliding up panel that doesn't update its ui when resumed but when recreated it does the job. I tried onResume() but no help!

Comment: Please have a look at this. I have tried to explain it as good as I can. https://stackoverflow.com/q/47239625/8745264

Comment: The relationship between that question and this one is not clear. Looking at that question I see static Java methods that refer to views stored in static fields. That's a huge red flag - you should literally never do that. Turn the fields (e.g. slidingUpPanelLayout) into regular fields.

Comment: I did that because I wanted to call those methods in different activities

Comment: Separate in your mind different instances of an activity, and different activity classes. If you have non-static methods in a base activity and extend different activity classes from it, you can still call those non static methods. A static field means you can have only value in it **for the entire app** - definitely not what you want. I think you'll need to read up on what 'static' means in Java.